# How do i temporarily store an image of the JPanel or PaintComponent in Java?

Tags: java, image, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm trying to make a paint program, and this class is the main area where you drag your mouse to paint.  The problem is the clip has to be rectangular, so any other lines within that rectangle of the clip (the clip gets bigger the faster you move) will get covered by the new clip, however the new clip isn't all needed.

My ideas of solutions are:

To somehow set the clip to a line (but I think that clip would have to be set in the repaint method, not the setClip() in paint component)

To save the image currently on the paint component and set it to the backgroud

Possibly set the ocupancy of the clip lower in the areas without the line?

Thank you for looking at it, here is the code (with some parts left out for simpler reading) and if you know a solution I would love to hear it.  Thanks!

```
public class Canvas extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener{

    int sizeX, sizeY;
    String title;
    int[] backColor = new int[3];
    int brushSize=20;
    Point currentP = new Point();
    Point pastP = new Point();
    Point paintP = new Point();
    int diffX, diffY;
    boolean initialize=true;
    boolean initClip=true;




    Canvas(){
        backColor[0] = newProject.colorA;
        backColor[1] = newProject.colorB;
        backColor[2] = newProject.colorC;


        if(backColor[0]>=255){
            backColor[0]=255;
        }
        if(backColor[1]>=255){
            backColor[1]=255;
        }
        if(backColor[2]>=255){
            backColor[2]=255;
        }
        sizeX = newProject.sizeX;
        sizeY = newProject.sizeY;

        //System.out.println(sizeX + " " + sizeY);
        setSize(sizeX,sizeY);
        setBackground(Color.white);
    }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(brushSize));
        if(initialize){
        g.setColor(new Color(backColor[0], backColor[1], backColor[2]));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
        System.out.println("Initialize");

        }
        else{

        g2.drawLine(currentP.x, currentP.y, pastP.x,pastP.y);
        }

        //System.out.println("Paint");
}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    if(initClip)                       //if mouse has been released since last dragged
        currentP = e.getPoint();   //This causes PastP and CurrentP to be equal 
        initClip=false;            //since pastP is set equal to CurrentP afterward
    pastP = currentP;
    currentP = e.getPoint();
    diffX=Math.abs(currentP.x-pastP.x);  //find the differences to find how big of 
    diffY=Math.abs(currentP.y-pastP.y);  //a clip it needs
    if(diffX==0){                        //if no movement, set it to brush size so the
        diffX=brushSize;             //clip shows up
    }
    if(diffY==0){
        diffY=brushSize;
    }
    initialize=false;


    if(currentP.x-pastP.x>0){    //figures out which direction it moved
        paintP.x=pastP.x;    //sets the clip variable to the correct corner
    }
    else{
        paintP.x=currentP.x;
    }

    if(currentP.y-pastP.y>0){
        paintP.y=pastP.y;
    }
    else{
        paintP.y=currentP.y;
    }
    System.out.println(paintP);
    repaint(paintP.x, paintP.y, diffX, diffY);  //repaint with point PaintP and the
                                                //difference it moved

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    initClip=true;


}
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing, at least to me. I have no idea what `"... however the new clip isn't all needed."` means for instance. What are you trying to do, again? Please tell us much more detail. Please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I am just rolling my head around my neck, Air is passing through the ear, read your question 3-4 times and.... no luck, i am stuck in the middle!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would bother.  Each time `paintComponent` is called by the paint system, you are expected to repaint the entire component anyway.

Instead, simply paint what you need to paint, then paint the selection on top of it...

[image]

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class DrawSelection {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DrawSelection();
    }

    public DrawSelection() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage background;
        private Rectangle clipRect;

        public TestPane() {
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/your/image"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            MouseAdapter ma = new MouseAdapter() {

                private Point cp;

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                    cp = e.getPoint();
                    clipRect = null;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                    cp = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                    Point p = e.getPoint();
                    int x = Math.min(p.x, cp.x);
                    int y = Math.min(p.y, cp.y);
                    int width = Math.max(p.x, cp.x) - x;
                    int height = Math.max(p.y, cp.y) - y;
                    clipRect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
                    repaint();
                }


            };

            addMouseListener(ma);
            addMouseMotionListener(ma);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return background == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(background.getWidth(), background.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (background != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
            }
            if (clipRect != null) {

                g2d.setColor(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionBackground"));
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(0.5f));
                g2d.fill(clipRect);

            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

If you want to optimise the paint process, why not draw the parts of the image to a backing buffer and simply paint the buffer, then paint the selection or other dynamic parts on top of it within the `paintComponent`?